# Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Actually I tried it so that i can have my navigation drawer below my app bar and along with tabs and main content.I also have to include coordinator layout also for a fab. Help me out and tell if i can use coordinator layout where i used for fab.

Updated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainapp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_draw_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/main_content" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fabmenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_fab_label="Cancel"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#795548"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Add Note" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#2196f3"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Add Question" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
01-29 00:54:36.358 27098-27098/myandroid.projecttries.testapp19 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: myandroid.projecttries.testapp19, PID: 27098
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myandroid.projecttries.testapp19/myandroid.projecttries.testapp19.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
      at myandroid.projecttries.testapp19.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myandroid.projecttries.testapp19-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
      at myandroid.projecttries.testapp19.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 22 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone faced same issue: the key is to replace

```
android.support.v4.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

with

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

in tag name. Eg:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be correct answer to your question but you can try like this for a navigation view coming under the app Bar using new Design Support Library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>      
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton_ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/yourdiesiredicon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
    app:fabSize="normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope that i helped you.!

Comment: But don' we need Drawer Layout for Navigation drawer

Comment: @MohammadAasif did that xml help you.?

Comment: Actually I didn't try, I thought Drawer Layout is necessary. I am a real beginner and confused. I will try now.

Comment: yup i added :) no tension .

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to build.gradle...

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```